# MySQL said: Documentation (#1064) - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a table in my mysql database and I keep getting this error. Please help, code is below:

```
CREATE TABLE 'Test'.'Sensor' (
'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
'time' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
'value' VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL,
)
```

The Error is:

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
>   near ''Test'.'Sensor' ( 'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
>   'time' TIMES' at line 1

Comment: MySql **is not** SQL Server.

Comment: In PHP, `session_start()` is not the same as `'session_start()'`. The same concept applies to SQL and many other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotes and try like this:-

```
CREATE TABLE Test.Sensor ( 
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    value VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have chosen your database then why you are using test. ?

`CREATE TABLE Sensor ( 
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    value VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL 
);`